# Grayscale in IE 10 and 11?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to figure out how to get grayscale to work in IE 10 and 11. I have a grid of icons that I want to grayscale. It's built something like this:

```
<ul class="medium-block-grid-4 large-block-grid-4">

    <li>
        <a href="#"><figure class="cap-bot report-10x10">
            <figcaption>Caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean egestas lectus non odio bibendum iaculis. Proin a lorem purus.</figcaption>
        </figure></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#"><figure class="cap-bot report-10kbonus locked">
            <figcaption><i class="fa fa-lock fa-5x fa-fw" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;"></i><br> Caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean egestas lectus non odio bibendum iaculis. Proin a lorem purus.</figcaption>
        </figure></a>
    </li>

<ul>
```

The first figure is full color. The second figure contains the classes "locked grayscale" which makes the whole figure gray. It's working fine in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. But it doesn't work in IE.

I've looked at various solutions and tried to implement some jQuery plugins (such as [this one](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray) and [this one](http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js-v2-0-with-browser-feature-detection-using-modernizr/)), but it seems like of them are written specifically to grayscale images. Is there a way to grayscale items in IE that aren't images? My icons are contained in square blue divs with blue borders, and I'd like to force everything to be gray.

**UPDATE:** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/regularmegs/08prwLLL/3/) with the icons in question.

Comment: What format are the icons in? If they're not images, are they SVG or something like that? Or if they are images, why can't you just specify your own gray colors for the background and border?

Comment: These icons look like [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons and they can be styled using the CSS `color` property to gray (e.g. `#ccc`) or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified: the FontAwesome lock icons overlay on top of my custom icons (which are .pngs assigned as background images to each figure). I need the whole figure to gray out if the class "locked" is assigned to it.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```css
a i.fa{color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>    
<li>
    <a href="#"><figure class="fig-1 cap-bot">
        <figcaption><i class="fa fa-lock fa-5x fa-fw" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;"></i><br>Caption goes here.</figcaption>
    </figure></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"><figure class="fig-2 cap-bot locked grayscale">
        <figcaption><i class="fa fa-lock fa-5x fa-fw" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;"></i><br>Caption goes here.</figcaption>
    </figure></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't just want to change the Font Awesome icons. Please see my comment above.

Comment: Your fiddle does not have any fontawesome icons in it. So are you or are you not using them? A little confused as to what you actually want and now your html is different than your original question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I needed to update the link when I updated the fiddle. I want to grayscale the entire figure and all of its contents including both the font awesome icon and my own icons (which are background images on the figures). It's working in every browser except IE.